# Find the best prototype design tool

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am developing a Windows GUI Application. I need a tool to create a prototype design. Please help me to find the best tools? Thanks.

Comment: [Here](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GuiPrototypingTools) is GUI prototyping tool list. Maybe you'll find what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visio have some stencils for Windows GUI which can be used to prototype a design.

Another option is to use the Visual Studio designer (for either WPF or WinForms) and just layout the forms, without any code.

Comment: Visio doesn't have any components, ex: DataGridView, ... How to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: I think Visual Studio is not good, because application's designers don't know to use VS, they will need a simple tools to design quickly, and coders will create a application' GUI based on the design pattern.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on whether you want a free tool or a paid for one, plus what technology you're going to use in the long run.

For winforms, Anders answer is probably best.

If you're aiming at using Silverlight or WPF then I'd recommend Expression Blend as you can produce a rough working GUI design and quickly transform it into working code.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft [SketchFlow](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/sketchflow_overview.aspx) seems like a quite good tool.
You can create more or less working prototypes, the standard skin of the prototypes are pencil-sketch style to give the viewer a feeling that the prototype is just a prototype and not a working application.

If you want to show examples of final look'n feel you can just use the regular WinForms or WPF designer.

Answer (score 0):

I use this one a lot.  It's easy to put stuff together and there is a wealth of addons to meet your gui needs.

[Balsamiq](http://www.balsamiq.com/)